# What is the shortest way to write this regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have the following pattern:

```
\<\?php\s*\/\*\s*magicNoteStart\s*\*\/([\w\W]*)\s*\/\*\s*magicNoteEnd\s*\*\/\s*\?\>
```

To match against the following sample:

```
<?php
/* magicNoteStart */
$ancillaries = array(
    'Page Information' => array(
        'hidden' => true
    ),
    'Metadata' => array(
        'hidden' => true
    ),
    'Revision Note' => array(
        'hidden' => true
    )
);
/* magicNoteEnd */
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test HTML</title>
    </head>
</html>
```

So the aim is to be able to use the regex for both a `preg_match()` and a `preg_replace()`.

When used with `preg_replace()` it should remove the entire PHP portion of code at the top of the sample so I currently have:

```
$contents = preg_replace(self::$magic_note_regex, '', $contents, 1);
```

`preg_match()` is used to extract everything between the `/* magicNoteStart */` and `/* magicNoteEnd */` so it can effectively be `eval()`ed. Currently my code for this looks like:

```
if(preg_match(self::$magic_note_regex, $contents, $matches)) {
    return trim($matches[1]);
}
```

This is in a legacy system and I am unable to break backwards compatibility. I cannot guarantee how much whitespace there will be between anything hence my overuse of `\s*` in the pattern I have entered above.

So what is the shortest way to write this regex?

Comment: And your question/problem is...?

Comment: Umm.... the question is in the title: What is the shortest way to write this regex? I have now edited the body of the question to include a duplicate of the question in the title.

Comment: Sure, I read the title, but your question doesn't state, why you would want to do this. You provided a lot of code and your questions reads as if everything is working. Without stating the problem that leads you to wanting a shorter regex, it is hard to answer the question, at least for me.

Comment: Is the php block allways at the beginning of a file? If yes, you could remove the whole regex-thing, and just use the first chunk before `?>`?! (Like: `list($magic) = explode('?>', $code, 2);`

Comment: That regexp works fine, I've tested it. Why do you want to rewrite it? Only one note: you don't have to escape < and >, they are not special characters in regexp.

Comment: You can also use regex delimiters other than forward slash (`/`).  So you could use `#`, which means that you don't have to escape all those forward slashes.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth My aim is to make it shorter so that it is easier to read and hold the various aspects in your head as you decipher the regex.

Comment: @J0HN thanks I have now removed these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pattern = "#/\*\s*magicNoteStart\s*\*/.*\*\s*magicNoteEnd\s*\*/#s";
```

I've ignored the PHP tags, but you can add them back in if required.

Comment: Thanks. I was already using percent signs delimiters, but had forgotten this meant I could drop escaping the slashes.

Comment: I now have `%<\?php\s*/\*\s*magicNoteStart\s*\*/([\w\W]*)\s*/\*\s*magicNoteEnd\s*\*/\s*\?>%` as I cannot for the life me get the `.*` to work. It just stops matching as soon as I add it in hence my `\w\W`. Its weird.

Comment: Ah I need DOTALL: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php Missed the s modifier in your regex

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
(\/\*\s*magicNoteStart\s*\*\/.*magicNoteEnd\s*\*\) //(I didd't test it)
```

since you want to eval it, the comments will be ignored .